# Getting kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException ArrayList<Album> in HomeAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Getting kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException in getItemCount(). albumList return null. Maybe I am not declaring albumList properly. I am new to Kotlin. But I have did in Java successfully.

### This is my Home Class

```
    private var adapter: HomeAdapter? = null
    private var albumList: ArrayList<Album>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        albumList = ArrayList<Album>()

        adapter = HomeAdapter(albumList)
        recyclerView!!.adapter = adapter
     }
```

### This is Adapter

```
class HomeAdapter(albumList: ArrayList<Album>?) : RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.MyViewHolder>()
{
    private var HomeContext: Context? = null
    private var albumList: ArrayList<Album>? = null

    fun HomeAdapter(albumList: ArrayList<Album>)
    {
        this.HomeContext = HomeContext
        this.albumList = albumList
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return albumList!!.size!!
    }
}
```

### This my Album

```
class Album(s: String, i: Int)
{
    private var name: String? = null
    private var thumbnail: Int = 0

    fun Album(name: String, thumbnail: Int)
    {
        this.name = name
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `fun HomeAdapter()` **is not** the constructor, hence `albumList` is never correctly assigned to a non-null value.

In general that code looks like an attempt to translate from Java to Kotlin and is quite misleading, being far from idiomatic Kotlin. In order to have a better idea of what it should look like, I'd suggest you to read the official documentation ([here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/)) and to use the automatic Java to Kotlin conversion offered by IntelliJ Idea, for instance.

To give you an idea, that's the equivalent Java code for the `Album` class above:

```
public final class Album {
    private String name;
    private int thumbnail;

    public Album(String s, int i) {
        super();
        // Note you're not using "s" and "i" here
    }

    public final void Album(String name, int thumbnail) {
        this.name = name;
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
        // note this is an instance method, not the constructor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have another look at the documentation. But to fix your code this is how your adapter should look and you pass the values in the constructor and you don't have to worry about nulls since you don't pass any nulls

```
class HomeAdapter(val context: Context, val albumList: ArrayList<Album>): RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.MyViewHolder>(){

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return albumList.size
    }
}
```

and this is your Album Pojo if you want to be able to reasign the variables then you declare them as var because you use data you get automatically toString, equals and hashCode

```
data class Album(val name: String, val thumbnailID: Int)
```